# How to pass a string with spaces to 'CONTAINS' IN T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, filetable

How to pass a string `This is a sample` to `CONTAINS` in "File Table" in SQL Server 2012.

`CONTAINS` keyword does not accept spaces, brackets.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sample_FILETable 
WHERE CONTAINS (file_stream, 'This is a sample') ;
```

Comment: `WHERE file_stream IN('This is a sample')` Contains will be removed in future sql server versions anyway

Comment: thank you. Didn't knew 'Contains'  is going to be removed in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Like`

```
SELECT * FROM Sample_FILETable where file_stream like '%This is a sample%'
```

Comment: **Contains** works on full indexed fields, using **like** on such fileds in a huge DB is not suitable, IMHO.